# Function voxel_metrics in lidR 4.0.1 gives error "Argument is not a LAS object" when used with a LAScatalog

Tags: r, las, lidr

I am attempting to use the `lidR` `voxel_metrics()` function to compute leaf area density across a large spatial extent. Due to the size of the LAS file (~10 GB) I have imported it as a `LAScatalog` object using chunk processing. The documentation for `lidR` states that `voxel_metrics()` requires an argument of either a `LAS` or `LAScatalog` object but the following error results when attempting to run it with a `LAScatalog`.

```r
ctg2 = readLAScatalog("E:/branching_data/CO/CO_site72.las", filter = "-drop_withheld")
voxel_metrics(ctg2, ~LAD(Z), res=1)
#> Error: Argument is not a LAS object
```

I have tried using several different `LAS` files, including much smaller ones, and the error persists. `pixel_metrics()` reliably works with `LAScatalog` objects as far as I can tell, but other `*_metrics()` functions give a slightly different error message:

```r
cloud_metrics(ctg2, ~mean(Z))
#> Error in UseMethod("cloud_metrics", las) : 
#>  no applicable method for 'cloud_metrics' applied to an object of class "LAScatalog"
```

Is there another way I can calculate voxel metrics using a `LAScatalog`?

Comment: I could answer this question in depth but I think it would be useless. Your real problem here is that `LAD` is meaningless with `voxel_metric()`. Its definition does not allows to compute it for voxels. And even with `pixel_metrics()` it won't work. `LAD` returns a `data.frame` not a number. It is not a metric. What the original authors used was the coefficient of variation of the LAD as metric per pixel.

Comment: Thank you! That clears things up.