# How to calculate voxel metrics for a LAScatalog using lidR?

Tags: lidar, lidr

I'm trying to calculate metrics for a LAScatalog with the voxel_metrics function. This is the code I used:

```
library(lidR)
ctg <- readLAScatalog("laspath")
voxel_metrics(ctg, ~mean(Z), 4)
```

When I run it, I get this message:

```
Error: Argument is not a LAS object
```

Can the voxel_metrics function be used with a LAScatalog? (A similar question was asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434969/function-voxel-metrics-in-lidr-4-0-1-gives-error-argument-is-not-a-las-object), but I don't think the answer applies in this case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`voxel_metrics` does not have a version for `LAScatalog`. The reason is that the output is a `data.frame`. Unlike spatial objects like `sf`, `SpatRaster` or `LAS` a `data.frame` can contain anything. It is thus impossible to let the `LAScatalog` processing engine automatically handle the logic of a function returning a `data.frame`.

You could convert it into `sf` with `PointZ` geometries and record it into geopackage files. This would looks like this

```r
opt_output_files(ctg) = "/path/file/to/export_{ID}"
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) = 10
ctg@output_options$drivers$sf$extension = ".gpkg"

apply_vm = function(las)
{
  m = voxel_metrics(las, 8,  ~mean(Intensity))
  m = sf::st_as_sf(m, coords = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
}

res = catalog_map(ctg, apply_vm)
```

If your dataset if small enough, you can remove `opt_output_files(ctg)` to return everything in R as one big `sf` object.

You are free to find another solution that fits your need. This is just a quick solution I can offer right now.